# Insert from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following tables: `data_1`, `data_1`, `data_3`, `data_4`, (data_*).

All of them of same fields name.

I want to INSERT all the error entries `(where error != ''`) from those tables into `data_error` table but only specific fields.

How can that be archived?

Comment: Sounds like you should have normalized your database schema. What means "...but only specific fields"?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go through all tables following a certain rule for the table name:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `TEST_TABLE_LOOP` ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE data_TableName VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE is_Done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

    DECLARE insert_MainCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name LIKE '<FILTER GOES HERE>';

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET is_Done = TRUE;

    OPEN insert_MainCursor;

    read_loop:LOOP
        FETCH insert_MainCursor INTO data_TableName;

        IF is_Done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        SET @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO <DESTINATION_TABLE_NAME_HERE> SELECT <COLUMN1>, <COLUMN2> FROM ', data_TableName, ' WHERE <SOMETHING_SOMETHING_GOES_HERE>');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; 
        EXECUTE stmt; 
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    END LOOP read_loop;

    CLOSE insert_MainCursor;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like:

```
insert into table (fields)
  select field from data_1
    where error <> 1;
```

If you wanted to do this in a single query with all the tables, you could do something

```
insert into table (fields)
  select field from data_1
    where error <> 1
  UNION
  select field from data_2
    where error <> 1
  UNION
  select field from data_3
    where error <> 1;
```

and so on..

Comment: can `data_1` be wildcard? eg: `data_*`

Comment: Not directly.  You COULD do this via a stored procedure though.  It would be the same idea, but you would first start by getting all the tables with that name and then looping through those.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO data_error (column1, column2, column3)
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM data_1
WHERE error != ''
UNION ALL
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM data_2
WHERE error != ''
UNION ALL
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM data_3
WHERE error != ''
UNION ALL
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM data_4
WHERE error != ''
```

[MySQL Ref](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: Thank you, is  `data_*` (wildcard) not possible?

Comment: It isn't possible using a wildcard.